# how to add search ajax function in this Pagination, Live Edit and Delete Records with Jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

http://demos.9lessons.info/EditDeletePagination/
how to add search ajax function with a texbox input that can let user to search specific data in this live edit and delete records with Jquery?

Answer (score -1):

hope you know how to use jquery AJAX.

follow d steps

1. Call AJAX function that will get response from your server
2. On server side process the posted data to build the query and get data accordingly from you database
3. Return html rendered text
4. Replace the response in the div where you want to show the data

Pass PageIndex, PageSize & Other where conditions for search in AJAX and get response accordingly.

If you cannot return HTML rendered then return the json and use **jquery template** so that you can easily assing your json as binding source to your template